# Change Text in Textfile with Search & Replace + Regex | Batchfile

Tags: regex, vbscript

I need to write a .bat/.cmd/.vbs file that changes the text of a text file and I also need regex terms.

I have the following text file as .txt.

```
"Bild/Print/59/00-Einstiegsbild-neu_59115.jpg" -resize 227.05x227.05%% -rotate -0 -shear 0x0 -crop 2011x1051+104+328 "web\00-Einstiegsbild-neu_59115.jpg"
"Bild/Print/59/01-Zwischenbild-neu_59150.jpg" -resize 100.39x100.39%% -rotate -0 -shear 0x0 -crop 2012x988+0+82 "web\01-Zwischenbild-neu_59150.jpg"
```

Now I want to do the following regex search and replace:

```
(1. Replace)
Search: "
Replace: (nothing)
```

```
(2. Replace)
Search: .+(?=web)
Replace: (nothing)
```

Now the text should be:

```
web\00-Einstiegsbild-neu_59115.jpg
web\01-Zwischenbild-neu_59150.jpg
```

```
(3. Replace)
Search: web\\
Replace: E:\K4_XML_Export\tpx_K4toWP_ImageMagick\web\
```

which should result in:

```
E:\K4_XML_Export\tpx_K4toWP_ImageMagick\web\00-Einstiegsbild-neu_59115.jpg
E:\K4_XML_Export\tpx_K4toWP_ImageMagick\web\01-Zwischenbild-neu_59150.jpg
```

Since I have absolutely no idea about batch files I hope you can help me further or share certain approaches or considerations.

Thank you in advance for the feedback and best regards
Noel

What I already tested – I know how to change text like red to blue with:

```
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strFile = "E:\imglist_2.txt"
Set objFile = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFile)
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = objFile.ReadLine
    If InStr(strLine,"red")> 0 Then
        strLine = Replace(strLine,"red","blue")
    End If 
    WScript.Echo strLine
Loop 

cscript /nologo E:\test.vbs > newfile
ren newfile file.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps... Regular expression can skip a few steps ahead and just grab the string (web...) without needing the redundant steps. Resulting in the desired pattern output.

*Please note you'll need to update this version back to your file strFile = "E:\imglist_2.txt"*

```
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
Dim objFS, objFile, PrimaryPath, strFile

PrimaryPath="E:\K4_XML_Export\tpx_K4toWP_ImageMagick"
strFile = "imagelist.txt"

Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFile, ForReading)

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = objFile.ReadLine
    If InStr(strLine,"web")> 0 Then ImagePath = PrimaryPath & "\" & GetWebImg(strLine)
    WScript.Echo ImagePath
Loop 

Function GetWebImg(str)
    Set RE = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    RE.Global = True
    RE.Pattern = "(web[^""]*)"
    Set matches = RE.Execute(str)
    If matches.count > 0 Then
        GetWebImg=matches(0)
    End If
End Function
```